# MySQL INSERT Statement Inserting Too Many Rows

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to insert a row in a MySQL if a row already exists in the same table with `nick` in it. Here is the query I'm attempting:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO gold_log (nick, amount, stream_online, modification_type, dt)
    SELECT DISTINCT nick, 0, 0, 253, DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-01-01 00:00:00')
    FROM gold_log WHERE nick='PrestonConnors';
```

I get result:

```
Query OK, 2243 rows affected, 2 warnings (0.24 sec)
Records: 2243  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 2
```

When I run the **SELECT** statement independently it only returns one result (which is what I expect):

```
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT nick, 0, 0, 253, DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-01-01 00:00:00') FROM gold_log WHERE nick='PrestonConnors';
+----------------+---+---+-----+-----------------------------------------+
| nick           | 0 | 0 | 253 | DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-01-01 00:00:00') |
+----------------+---+---+-----+-----------------------------------------+
| PrestonConnors | 0 | 0 | 253 | 2015-01-01 00:00:00                     |
+----------------+---+---+-----+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Can someone help form my **INSERT IGNORE INTO** statement into one that will only **INSERT** one row into the table and also explain what was wrong with my query?

Here is the layout of the table:

```
mysql> describe gold_log;
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| nick              | char(25)            | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| amount            | decimal(10,4)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| stream_online     | tinyint(1)          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| modification_type | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| dt                | datetime            | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And here are the warnings:

```
mysql> SHOW warnings;
+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1592 | Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. INSERT IGNORE... SELECT is unsafe because the order in which rows are retrieved by the SELECT determines which (if any) rows are ignored. This order cannot be predicted and may differ on master and the slave.                                                              |
| Note  | 1592 | Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. Statements writing to a table with an auto-increment column after selecting from another table are unsafe because the order in which rows are retrieved determines what (if any) rows will be written. This order cannot be predicted and may differ on master and the slave. |
+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Do you actually see multiple NEW rows after your insert runs? Are they identical?

Comment: as Darius, I would tend to question the number of "affected" rows, maybe misleading

Comment: try to replace `NOW()` with some conatsnt

Comment: @houssam I have added the table layout in the question. The primary keys are id and nick

@DariusX. The rows are identical except for the ``id`` column.

Comment: What are the warnings? Type `show warnings` directly after your `insert ignore...` to see them.

Comment: in the first query: NOW() made a lot of records as DISTINCT because it returns different values for each record, the query need too time to be executed ... but in the second query: NOW() returns the same value for each record (fast query) .

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand I have added the warnings to the original question.

@houssam I used a hard coded date (``'2015-01-01'``) and I still had duplicate rows inserted.

Answer (score -1):

Simply, It is a  bug in MySQL (I found it in mysql5.5.16); but when I update to (5.6.24):

```
mysql> status
--------------
D:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.24, for Win32 (x86)
```

It works properly.
See: 
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=58637 
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72921

Comment: No, that is related to the warnings, not to the actual behaviour OP asks about.